# how to get contact group using Microsoft Graph api or similier apis

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

We know this request below will return your current contacts from Outlook ..

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts

but what if I want to get a Group of contacts (the folder where I collect my contacts).  What should the request look like? I search in Microsoft docs.  I didn't find anything or maybe I searched in wrong place. Any another possibilities to get contacts even over another apis such (outlook-rest-api).

**What I did but that not my attention:**

code below over graph sdk to retrieve 1000 contacts:

```
var contacts = await graphClient.Me.Contacts.Request().Top(1000).GetAsync();
```

**Is there something like that ?**

```
var GroupOfcontacts = await graphClient.Me.GroupContacts.Request().GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually i saw this in Microsoft Docs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-contactfolders

i got contacts inside that folder
thank folderid, which i can get it through iterating over Contactfolders property
like that :

```
var contactFolders = await graphClient.Me.ContactFolders.Request().GetAsync();

foreach (folder in contactFolders) {

    var folderContacts = await            
      graphClient.Me.ContactFolders[folder.Id].Contacts.Request().GetAsync();
}
```