# Contact group using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-contacts

How to fetch contact groups, also called contact lists in Outlook web (not [contact folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-contactfolders?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)) using Microsoft Graph API?
[List contacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-contacts?view=graph-rest-1.0) and [list contact folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-contactfolders?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) doesn't fetch contact groups.

Created a [uservoice](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform/label-name/Microsoft%20Graph) for this feature: [link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/fetch-contact-group-using-graph-api/idi-p/3262621).
Do support if you think there's no feature currently avaliable to do this!

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/63268396/6271132

Comment: no @Mabiyan that one is for fetching contacts inside contact folders. And I want to list contact groups, which is different from contact folder.